# Python Selenium Extraction of Buried Variable

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, extract

I have been doing some work recently with Python's Selenium package and came across this weird HTML format that I have never seen before (posted below).  From this HTML page source, I would like to extract the value '-26.507', but it does not have a clear identifier.  What is the best way to approach this issue?  I have thought about using xpath but I am unsure how to implement it correctly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US" xml:lang="en-US"><head>
<title>GEOID COMPUTATIONS</title>
<link rev="made" href="mailto:-bgcolor" />
<base href="http://www.ngs.noaa.gov/cgi-bin/GEOID_STUFF/geoid12B_single.prl" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
</head>
<body>
<h2>Output from GEOID12B</h2><pre>                                         latitude        longitude       N         error (95% confidence interval)
Station Name                            ddd mm ss.sssss ddd mm ss.sssss  meters    meters
USER LOCATION                            28  0  0.00000  95  0  0.00000  -26.507    0.096
</pre>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Use xpath t get the contents of the `pre` element.  The text of that element appears to be a table and so you could use pandas to a simple regex to interpret it and extract the value you need

Comment: The closest you can get with Selenium is the content of the `<pre>` tag.  From there you'll  have to do something like call `.splitlines()` to break it into lines, then call `.split()` on the third line to break it into fields, then grab the desired field.

Comment: And shame on them for presenting tabular data as `<pre>` text.

Comment: Can you share with us your code trials?